# Storing a value in dataframe column but not registered in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have created an empty dataframe with column names. I tried to append a value under 'Company' column. The code works fine without throwing errors but it is not saved into the dataframe.

Google in internet and I see most solutions add data into existing dataframe this way. Did I miss anything?

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
from datetime import date

#Create new DF
colNames = ['Company', 'Ticker', 'Price', 'Quantity', 'Value', 'Percentage']
dfResults = pd.DataFrame(columns=colNames)

dfResults.append([{'Company':'test'}],ignore_index=True)

dfResults
```

The results:

```
Out[2]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Company, Ticker, Price, Quantity, Value, Percentage]
Index: []
```

Comment: your code is probably working just fine.  But ```append``` doesn't happen in-place, so you'll have to store the output if you want it ```new = dfResults.append([{'Company':'test'}],ignore_index=True)```, and then ```print(new)```

Comment: `.append` create a new DF so your result is lost in this code, because you are printing the old one